# access to backflow preventer assembly

Tags: bathroom, basement, backflow-preventer

My backflow preventer assembly access is in my basement and its right below the proposed vanity space in our proposed basement bathroom.(we have planned a 48 inch vanity , but if i cut down to a 36 inch vanity then backflow preventer access will be exactly in between the bathroom wall and vanity which will give 4 inch on either side. is that a problem , any alternative or suggestions please. I live in salt lake county (utah)

Comment: Backflow preventer for what?

Comment: So is your concern that if the "backflow preventer" would have only 4 inches on each side that this would be in too constricted a space for servicing or replacement?

Comment: Do you need a fixed vanity? What about putting in a pedestal lavatory?

Comment: What type of backflow preventer assembly is this?

Comment: @JimStewart yes thats my concern it will  only have 4 inches on either side , not sure if  thats a code violation. pedestal is not an option there given the space is very limited

Comment: @isherwood its blackflow preventer valve for main sewer  so prevent any backflow from city sewer system

Comment: I thought that a pedestal lavatory would give you *more* room for the 
anti-backflow valve which would be restricted by the side of a vanity.